# Ver se existe um ficheiro numa pasta c#

Tags: c#

Queria que verificasse se o ficheiro que o utilizador escolheu, já existe numa determinada pasta definida pelo menos. Se não existir, pode copiar o ficheiro.

Comment: Fiquei um pouco confuso, seu titulo pede uma coisa e a pergunta outra... Você quer ver se ele existe ou criar uma copia? edite sua pergunta para deixar mais claro

Comment: Programadores brasileiros; escrevem o requisito funcional e pedem ajuda técnica. Pelo o que pude entender, ela quer fazer um backup do arquivo que vai ser selecionado, e abrir neste novo diretório. Entretanto o trecho de código ainda mal faz a tarefa, logo acho que ela quer um método completo que faça isso.

Comment: Já corrigi. O meu problema mesmo @AndrewPaes, é que não sei mesmo como fazer essa parte de verificar se existe o ficheiro.

Comment: Bem, agora estamos começando a esclarecer. A resposta abaixo já é metade do caminho, porém, você quer verificar somente a existência do arquivo, ou comparar eles também? Por data? por conteúdo? por quantidade de bytes? Existem muitas verificações possíveis para um arquivo. Acredito que verificar a existência com FileExists() é a primordial, depois pode verificar última data de atualização, e depois quantidade de bytes. se for arquivo texto, ainda poderia fazer um "diff", mas isso é bem mais elaborado.

Comment: Eu ainda não consegui entender oque precisa ser feito, ainda que abiu um caminho

Comment: Fechei porque as respostas parecem ser chutes do que está querendo, e o fato delas serem opostas e ambas receberem votos parece que está tudo sem sentido aqui, só vai prejudicar outras pessoas que lerem aqui. Reabro quando der para entender o que precisa.

Comment: Já consegui fazer. Obrigada a todos e desculpem a minha confusão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só fazer a cópia do arquivo para uma pasta e executar este que foi copiado.
Não entendi seu código, mas fiz um exemplo para tentar te auxiliar.

```
private void AbrirArquivo()
{
        string arquivo = listView.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString();
        string diretorio = @"C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\";
        string diretorioBkp = @"C:\ByMe\SOLUTIONS\Dictation1\Database\Updates\Backup\";


        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(diretorio+arquivo);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
              FileInfo fBkp = new FileInfo(diretorioBkp + arquivo);
              if (fBkp.Exists)
              {
                  //se já existir uma cópia, deleto.
                  fBkp.Delete();
              }
              //faço a cópia do arquivo para a pasta bkp
              file.CopyTo(fBkp.FullName);
              //Abro o arquivo da pasta backup, o arquivo raiz, continua inalterado
              System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fBkp.FullName);
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Arquivo selecionado não existe!");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para verificar se o arquivo existe, ou trabalhar(copiar, ler, criar e etc) com arquivos, utilize a classe [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.Exists("Destino do arquivo")
```

Então basta chegar se o mesmo não existe com um [operador de negação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1k6w8551.aspx) "!" e caso ele não exista você faz a copia :D

```
//Se diferente de verdadeiro  
if(!File.Exists("Destino do arquivo"))
{
//Cria o arquivo
File.Copy("Caminho do arquivo","Destino do arquivo");
}
```